# Command substitution not occurring for PS1 variable in zsh

Tags: zsh, quoting, command, prompt

I'm having the hardest time trying to get dynamically evaluated command output in my `PS1` prompt with *zsh* on Ubuntu 17.10. Here are a few attempts I've made (I begin in directory `/abc`, and the prompt is in bold):

```
$ export PS1="$(pwd) > "
/abc > cd /def
/abc > pwd
/def
/abc > export PS1="\$(pwd) > "
$(pwd) > export PS1='$(pwd) > '
$(pwd) > export PS1='\$(pwd) > '
\$(pwd) > [ragequit]
```

The first result is the closest, but it looks like the `pwd` command is being evaluated only once when I define the `PS1` variable. Clearly there's something that I don't understand. What can I do to get `$(<cmd>)` reevaluated every time the command prompt is displayed?

Comment: Note that in zsh, a `precmd` function and setting `psvar` tends to be easier for doing complicated things than using `prompt_subst`. And for simple things there's prompt expansion, e.g. `%~` for the current directory.

Comment: @Gilles : I understand. I used 'pwd' as a universally recognized command. The real value of the variable is '$(ps1)', where the ps1 command will do whatever I ask it to do - e.g., show the current Git branch. :)

Comment: Showing the current git branch is a typical use case of `precmd`. That's how [`vcs_info` bundled with zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Version-Control-Information) does it.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm a stickler - I like to see things in a specific way, and I like my config files to be as uncluttered as I can make them. No accounting for taste, hm?

Comment: I'm not saying you should use `vcs_info`. (I don't either.) I'm saying that if you do something similar, you'll have an easier time using `precmd` and keeping `PS1` itself very simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the `zsh` shell to perform command substitution on the value of `PS1`, set the `PROMPT_SUBST` shell option:

```
set -o PROMPT_SUBST
PS1='$(pwd) > '
```

Note that there is no need to `export` the `PS1` variable.

The reason why the `PROMPT_SUBST` shell option is not set by default is likely that the `zsh` shell already has rich syntax for prompt expansions.

Your example could, for instance, be replaced by

```
PS1='%/ > '
```

For more information about this, see the "EXPANSION OF PROMPT SEQUENCES" section in the `zshmisc` manual on your system.

---

When you use

```
PS1="$(pwd) > "
```

the value given to the `PS1` variable is expanded before the assignment takes place. This is why it does not change when you change directories.

Comment: Yes indeed. It's odd to me that PROMPT_SUBST isn't the default, but that's my problem. :) Thanks very much.

Comment: it also doesn't expand any basic variables containing colour codes that has been set just before wich I thought was odd. Setting the PROMPT_SUBST didn't fix that.

Comment: @Brad `PROMPT_SUBST` affects all ordinary expansions that are part of a prompt. There are better ways to get color in the `zsh` shell's prompt. `%F{red}` sets the foreground color to red, for example. See the manual.

Comment: ah cheers Ive been trying to get my custom bash prompt to work in zsh 